# Timeout and redirect on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to redirect to another page a few seconds after submit. I'm using only JavaScript and Angularjs. I've found some examples, but they didn't work. Here's one of them:

```
vm.redirectTime = "1000";
        vm.redirectURL = "destination url";


       function redirect (){
            setTimeout("location.href = vm.redirectURL;", vm.redirectTime);
                       }
```

Can you help me with an example, please?

The idea is after submit show with ng-show a success message (which is working), and five or six seconds later, redirect to another page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: setTimeout(function() { location.href = vm.redirectURL; }, vm.redirectTime);

Comment: It works but not on the submit action :(